# Matching regex pattern counting only unique values from a wordlist

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse strings that looks like these:

```
1p+3m-2u+21d
3p+1m-2u
```

My rules are as such:

- A character must be preceded by a number.
- Any of 'p', 'm', 'u' and 'd' is optional but must always occur in that order.
- You can only use each of the four characters once.
- There has to be at least one occurrence of a number and a character.
- Each paired occurrence of a number and one of the four letters must be separated by a plus or minus operator.

My current progress looks like this (using the Javascript Regex engine):

```
^([+-][0-9]+[pmud]){1,4}$
```

This follows all of my above rules except the single occurrence of each character. How do I rewrite my pattern to reflect that exclusivity?

If this isn't reflectable by regular expressions, is there an alternative way to write the match using Javascript?

Comment: Is `3p+4u` valid?

Comment: Yes, it is valid to leave out any of the four characters as long as there is at least one in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use optional groups here plus make sure the pattern does not match an empty string with some lookahead.

```
/^(?!$|[-+])(?:\d+p)?(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+m)?(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+u)?(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+d)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA9pnZ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!$|[-+])` - no empty string allowed (at least one "unit" must be present) and no `-` and `+` can appear at the start
- `(?:\d+p)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ digits followed with `p`
- `(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+m)?` - an optional sequence of start of string or `-`/`+` followed with 1+ digits followed with `m`
- `(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+u)?` - an optional sequence of start of string or `-`/`+` followed with 1+ digits followed with `u`
- `(?:(?:^|[+-])\d+d)?` - an optional sequence of start of string or `-`/`+` followed with 1+ digits followed with `d`.
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the answer and the great explanation.

Comment: @UndyingJellyfish Just occurred to me: if you do not want to match `+2m`, use `(?!$|[-+])` lookahead. I updated the answer.

Comment: +2m is behavior which I hadn't considered, will have to ask someone else on my team for that.

Comment: @UndyingJellyfish Well, the *Each paired occurrence of a number and one of the four letters must be separated by a plus or minus operator.* requirement sounds as if the `+` or `-` can only appear between the units.